# Prevent Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY creating empty directories

Tags: cmake

When I use `Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY` in my `CMakeLists.txt` file for a target, an empty directory is automatically created, even if there are no module files there.

Can I prevent it, or at least remove the empty directories after building? This is no big deal, especially for an out-of-source build, but since I have many targets, I'd prefer not having many empty directories (and it would also let me see which targets create module files).

(I think the same happens with `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH`, but I usually don't have it empty.)

Comment: Out-of-source build or in-source build? The former is encouraged and having a folder in the build directory does usually not matter. The latter is discouraged, so you cannot expect help from CMake.

Comment: @usr1234567 I'm using out-of-source builds. I modified the question to add some justification.